Are the s orbitals or p orbitals more involved in bonding within 3rd period elements
I understand that within most diatomic molecule systems such as nitrogen gas the electrons within the s-orbitals have a net nonbonding effect but the p-orbitals are the ones that are involved in bonding of the molecule. However, within molecules that contain multiple bonds such as H2O or CH2, I’m not sure whether it’s the s-orbitals or the p-orbitals within their respective centre atoms that are involved in the bonds. Also, I’m not sure whether or not that differs based on the period of the central atom (for example, the above examples all involved 2nd-period atoms, but would it differ if the centre atom was a 3rd period atom such as Si). If so please explain why. 
